# Animating height constraints using easing curves

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to animate a height constraint using an easing curve? I'm thinking of maybe some way to set up a `CAKeyFrameAnimation` with the values and timings I'd like, and somehow have it affect the height constraint.

I'm not sure if there's a separate animation calss for constraints that I can utilize for constraint keyFrames, or if there's something I'm missing with `CAKeyFrameAnimation` that would allow me to use that class, or if it's not possible.

**Edit:** Here's what I'm trying to make work for me, if anyone knows if I'm on the right path or not I'd appreciate some guidance:

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = newHeight

let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "frame.size.height")
animation.values = [self.frame.size.height, newHeight]
animation.keyTimes = [0, 1]
animation.duration = self.animationDuration
animation.delegate = self

self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "heightChange")
```

`newHeight` would be whatever I want the height to be. But this just pops the view to be taller without any animation. Am I using this correctly? Is this possible to do with constraints?

**Edit 2:** I should add, I want to use more complex easing functions than the defaults Apple provides as part of `UIView.animate(withDuraiton:...`.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/warrenm/AHEasing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use CAKeyframeAnimation. A UIView animation will do easing on animations to a constraint, just like any other animation:

```
myConstraintOutlet.constant = someNewValue
UIView.animate(
  duration: 0.5,
  delay: 0.0,
  options: .curveEaseInOut, //Use ease-in, ease-out timing.
  animations:  {

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  },
  completion: nil)
```

### Edit:

If you want custom timing, you could also use the UIView-based keyframe animation with the method `animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)` (UIView animation is a whole lot easier to use than `CAAnimations`.)

### Edit #2:

Or, if all you need is a different cubic easing curve, you can do that too. See the very last bit at this link: https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/a-look-at-uiview-animation-curves-part-3-edde651b6a7a

The key bit is this code snippet from that link:

```
circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)

let timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 5/6, 0.2, 2/6, 0.9)

CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(timingFunction)

UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {
    self.circleView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}

CATransaction.commit()
```

(That's not my code, it's Robert Gummesson's, from the link above. All credit for writing it goes to him.)

Comment: True, but I want to do some more complex easing functions as necessary for this instead of just ease-in or ease-out (or the other defaults that Apple provides)

Comment: It's looking like I may not be able to achieve quite the complexity I desire in iOS. I'd like to somehow implement complex easing curves, such as sinusoidal or elastic ease out, but doing that with keyFrames is nowhere near efficient enough, and `CAMediaTimingFunction` isn't complex enough for my purposes unfortunately.

Comment: Take a look at both the UIView spring animation methods (`animate(withDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:)` and `CASpringAnimation` (link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caspringanimation). Those might offer some of what you want.